# send message to specific channel upon ready/launch

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

im trying to find a way to send a message to a channel upon launch of the discord bot. I've tried using

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
client.on('ready', () => {
  channel = client.channels.cache.get('744630121213722696');
  channel.send('bot is up and running!');

})});
```

but no success, I get no error messages just no response from the bot

Comment: Remove the `on('ready')` handler from the `on('message')` handler. Consider: It is not possible to check for a bot's launch from inside any other kind of handler, since the bot's launch is the first handler. Don't nest event handlers.

Comment: You cannot place one event listener inside of another, this will cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 2 handlers in one. Take away the `client.on('message', (message) => {}`

So new code would be:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  channel = client.channels.cache.get('744630121213722696');
  channel.send('bot is up and running!');

});
```

Comment: but then i get an error saying `(node:7592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: channel is not defined`